# Arduino Accelerometer to Python Output

Tags: python, arduino, accelerometer, pyserial

I'm trying to take my arduino code, have it output a character, then have my python code take in that character and do a function (press up, down, left, or right). Right now my arduino code is giving me an output of the letter I want and I see that output when I run the python, but python is still not pressing the buttons like I need it to. Any help would be great!

Arduino Code:

```
int  xmin=250,xmax=330;
int  ymin=264,ymax=330;
int  zmin=268,zmax=400;
int n=0, nx=0, ny=0, nz=0, a=0;
int x,y,z;
String cad="";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}


void loop() {


  nx=1;ny=1;nz=1;a=1;
  x=analogRead(1);
  y=analogRead(2);
  z=analogRead(3);
  x=9-map(x,xmin,xmax,0,9);
  y=map(y,ymin,ymax,0,9);
  z=map(z,zmin,zmax,0,9);


  if (x<3) nx=0;
  if (x>5) nx=2;
  if (y<3) ny=0;
  if (y>5) ny=2;
  if (z<3) nz=0;
  if (z>5) nz=2;


  a=1+9*nz+nx+3*ny;

  if (a==25){
    Serial.write('A'); //Release
  }
  else if (a==18){
    Serial.write('B'); //Duck
  }
  else if (a==26){
    Serial.write('C'); //Move right
  }
  else if (a==10){
    Serial.write('D'); //Left
  }
  else if (a==22){
    Serial.write('D');
  }
  else if (a==16){
    Serial.write('E'); //Jump
  }
  delay(200);  

}
```

Python Code:

```
import serial
import time
import pyautogui


str_up="up"    
str_down="down"
str_left="left"
str_right="right"


ArduinoSerial = serial.Serial(port='/dev/tty.usbmodem14501', baudrate=115200)
time.sleep(2)

while 1:
  incoming =  str (ArduinoSerial.read(1)) #Read one byte from serial port
  print(incoming)

  if 'D' == incoming:
    pyautogui.keyDown(str_left)  # Press left and ...
    pyautogui.keyUp(str_left)    # release
  elif 'A' in incoming:
   pyautogui.keyUp(str_right) ## release and ...
   pyautogui.keyUp(str_right)   # release
  elif 'C' == incoming:
    pyautogui.keyDown(str_right) # Press right and ...
    pyautogui.keyUp(str_right)   # release
  elif 'B' == incoming:
    pyautogui.keyDown(str_down) ## Press down and ...
    pyautogui.keyUp(str_down)   # release
  elif 'E' == incoming:
    pyautogui.keyDown(str_up) ## Press up and ...
    pyautogui.keyUp(str_up)   # release 


  ArduinoSerial.reset_input_buffer()  # Flush the serial port
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-press-keydown-and-keyup-functions you can use the "press('up')" method instead of keyDown and keyUp. Maybe it's to quick to register? You could try a wait time in between.

Example:

```py
>>> pyautogui.keyDown('shift')  # hold down the shift key
>>> pyautogui.press('left')     # press the left arrow key
>>> pyautogui.press('left')     # press the left arrow key
>>> pyautogui.press('left')     # press the left arrow key
>>> pyautogui.keyUp('shift')    # release the shift key
```